# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Bool'

Tags: swift, boolean, option-type

I'm brand new to Swift (using Swift 4.1). I'm following some tutorials to try to learn the syntax. In the line of code:

```
if !message.isSender!.boolValue
```

I get an error saying:

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Bool'

I've surfed around and can't quite find or figure out a solution to the error.

```
if !message.isSender!.boolValue {
    cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 48 + 8, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)

    cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x: 48, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
} else {
    cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 48 + 8, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)

    cell.textBubbleView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - estimatedFrame, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
}
```

Comment: This would depend on how `message` and `isSender`are defined. Tell us.

Comment: What is type of variable "message" and "isSender"?

Comment: The only thing you're force unwrapping is `isSender` and that is a non-optional `Bool`.  So you probably just want `if !message.isSender {`.

Comment: Which tutorials are you following that tell you to use the `boolValue` property? That is unusual to see in Swift.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.  Among other things, you should hang around after posting and respond to comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's already a Bool, just use it:

```
if !message.isSender
```

There's no reason to unwrap, it's not an optional as the compiler's telling you, and there's no reason to access `boolValue` for a simple `if`.